# How can I add a check in my for-loop to replace newlines with spaces?

Tags: powershell

How would I go about adding a check at the end of my for loop to replace new lines with spaces?

```
cd C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\project-code\update-fields-script\
$fileDirectory="C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\project-code\update-fields-script\objects\"
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory)
{
    $outputfile="C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\project-code\update-fields-script\finalized_output\$file"
    Set-Content -Value '<entry key="force.extract" value="' -Path $outputfile
    ([xml] (Get-Content -Raw $fileDirectory\$file)).CustomObject.fields.fullName -join ', ' | Add-Content $outputfile
    $namefile="$file".Split('.')[0]
    Add-Content -Value " FROM $namefile`"/>" -Path $outputfile
}
```

I'm trying to get the `'<entry key="force.extract" value="'` text to continue right into the XML parsing and `" FROM $namefile`"/>"` text without breaking off into a new line from the **Add-Content** command.

Comment: `Out-File -FilePath $Path -Append -NoNewLine -Force` Also has the added benefit of not locking the file. (The `Add-Content` cmdlet also has `-NoNewLine` if you look at the help)

Comment: I tried that with the first *Add-Content* statement and it inserted a space between all the characters that were outputted by the XML parsing. I got around the last **Add-Content** with a -NoNewLine switch. Still the **Set-Content** pushes any additions to another line.

Comment: I fail to see why you're trying to do xml manipulation outside of the dom.

Comment: Looks like the -NoNewLine parameter resolved the issue. It's complicated. My Powershell skills are terrible atm.